# Why doesn't Java allow recursion in constructor?

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

I think allowing recursion can be very handy sometimes, not because I can code in "recursion" but rather because I can save some code space for some cases like below

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private int a;

   SomeClass(int a)
   {
      this.a = a;
   }

   SomeClass()
   {
      SomeClass(3);
   }
}
```

This is especially effective when one constructor tries to take advantage of another that contains big chunks of code.

However, Java clearly doesn't support this feature, and I believe it doesn't for a very good reason. Could anyone care to explain why though?

Comment: This isn't necessarily recursion, just calling the constructor with a default argument.

Comment: @AdelBoutros That's a bit harsh, don't you think.  A person is learning and has problems with the syntax - so asks a question.  The answer is quite simple, so why tell the person off?  You know, "there are no stupid questions, there are stupid answers".

Comment: @EvanMulawski - it isn't recursion ***at all***.

Comment: @AdelBoutros, didn't you see his code? " SomeClass(3); "  ??

Comment: @gt_ebuddy and? how does that answer my question?

Comment: @gt_ebuddy plus the question was closed for being not constructive. I don't think you know more than the high and respected contributors

Comment: @AdelBoutros, I agree that he should have googled it. But, isn't it obvious from his question that he tried something. We can clearly understand from his code and question that he is newbie. I meant to complain about the language of your first comment ( though you have deleted it. See Aleks G's comment for reference).

Comment: @AdelBoutros And, There is no point in saying that "plus the question was closed for being not constructive."  and  "I don't think you know more than the high and respected contributors". Its the matter of how well you care to encourage others. All I want to say that - Don't be that much rude. Because you were once a learner ; You  surely have passed the phases like user803253 going through now.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy I believe in every comment I write. Thus, I never delete them unless they are reported and closed by others. End of discussion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java does support this, but you need to use different syntax:

```
this(3);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can invoke another constructor within a constructor, using the `this` keyword:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private int a;

   SomeClass(int a)
   {
      this.a = a;
   }

   SomeClass()
   {
      this(3);
   }
}
```

From the Java Language Specification, section [8.8.7.1 Explicit Constructor Invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this
>   (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to
>   invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.

I don't see what does that have to do with [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `this(3)` instead of `SomeClass(3)`

Answer (score 0):

it is not called as recursive. Java has functionality that you can have overloaded constructor in your class....